# insert into a table having table name derived from subquery

Tags: mysql

I have tables named Student_Info table, Subject_Info table and an individual table belonging to each student containing information about each subject parameter for that student (like name of the subject, marks he got in that subject etc).

Student_Info

```
+----+----------+    
| Id | Name     |    
+----+----------+    
|  1 | Sam      |        
|  2 | Taylor   |   
|  3 | Rick     |
+----+----------+
```

Subject_Info

```
+---------------+    
| Subject_Name  |    
+---------------+    
|  Physics      |        
|  Chemistry    |   
|  Mathematics  |
+---------------+
```

1_Info

```
+---------------+-------+    
| Subject_Name  | Marks |     
+---------------+-------|    
|  Physics      |  60   |   
|  Chemistry    |  40   |
|  Mathematics  |  80   |
+---------------+-------+
```

2_Info

```
+---------------+-------+    
| Subject_Name  | Marks |     
+---------------+-------|    
|  Physics      |  70   |   
|  Chemistry    |  50   |
|  Mathematics  |  60   |
+---------------+-------+
```

3_Info

```
+---------------+-------+    
| Subject_Name  | Marks |     
+---------------+-------|    
|  Physics      |  70   |   
|  Chemistry    |  70   |
|  Mathematics  |  70   |
+---------------+-------+
```

Here the tables 1_Info, 2_Info, 3_Info are the tables corresponding to students with Id = 1, Id = 2, Id = 3 respectively.

My questions are

1. If I insert a subject name into the Subject_Info table I must insert the same subject name in all the individual tables corresponding to each student (1_Info, 2_Info, 3_Info).

I used the following query to get the table name; it works fine.

```
SELECT CONCAT(Id, '_Info') FROM Student_Info;
```

I tried to write it using a single query like this

```
INSERT INTO (SELECT CONCAT(Id, '_Info') FROM Student_Info) VALUES ('Physics');
```

But getting error.

Is it possibles to do this in single query?

If yes then where am I doing mistake?

2. Is it a good way to give names to the tables that I am using here for each students subject related parameters (1_Info, 2_Info etc)? If not please suggest a good way.

Comment: Please show your tables structure

Comment: Hi @MuhammadMuazzam, thanks for the reply. My working tables are different, cannot reveal it here. The example I gave here is likewise related to my working tables. Could you please let me know what exact you are asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be more easy to put the information in 1 Table, like this for example

```
Student
+----+--------+    
| Id | Name   |    
+----+--------+    
|  1 | Sam    |        
|  2 | Taylor |   
|  3 | Rick   |
+----+--------+


Subject
+----+-------------+    
| Id | Subject     |    
+----+-------------+    
|  1 | Physics     |        
|  2 | Chemistry   |   
|  3 | Mathematics |
+----+-------------+

Info
+------------+------------+-------+    
| student_id | subject_id | Marks |    
+------------+------------+-------+    
| 1          | 1          | 60    |
| 1          | 2          | 40    |
| 1          | 3          | 80    |
| 2          | 1          | 70    |
| 2          | 2          | 50    |
| 2          | 3          | 60    |
| 3          | 1          | 70    |
| 3          | 2          | 70    |
| 3          | 3          | 70    |
+------------+------------+-------+
```

And the INSERT would be

```
INSERT INTO Student(Name) VALUES('Tom');

INSERT INTO Subject(Subject) VALUES('History');

INSERT INTO Info(4, 4, 80);
```

EDIT: Alternative, this is what I think is called "Third Normal Form (3NF)"

```
Student
+----+--------+    
| Id | Name   |    
+----+--------+    
|  1 | Sam    |        
|  2 | Taylor |   
|  3 | Rick   |
+----+--------+


Subject
+----+-------------+    
| Id | Subject     |    
+----+-------------+    
|  1 | Physics     |        
|  2 | Chemistry   |   
|  3 | Mathematics |
+----+-------------+

Marks
+----+------+    
| Id | Mark |    
+----+------+    
|  1 | 60   |        
|  2 | 40   |   
|  3 | 80   |
|  4 | 70   |
|  5 | 50   |
+----+------+

Info
+------------+------------+---------+    
| student_id | subject_id | mark_id |    
+------------+------------+---------+    
| 1          | 1          | 1       |
| 1          | 2          | 2       |
| 1          | 3          | 3       |
| 2          | 1          | 4       |
| 2          | 2          | 5       |
| 2          | 3          | 1       |
| 3          | 1          | 4       |
| 3          | 2          | 4       |
| 3          | 3          | 4       |
+------------+------------+---------+
```

Comment: Hi @domacs, thanks for the reply. But I asked different questions. Could you have answer for them? I will be very glad if you could help me in solving my exact problem

Comment: sorry, im not 100% shure, but i dont think it is possible this way, so i replyed to you 2. point

Comment: Hi again @domacs, here I showed u an example only. But my actual tables are quite large and I read somewhere it is good to have smaller tables with less number of columns having repetitive data. And your answer is contradictory to this rule. Can u suggest some better and optimal way? Thanks again.

Comment: my answer is confirm to this rule, you can maybe crate a 4th table with Marks and Ids an put just ids into the info table. it would be wrong to make 1 table with all data inside and repeat some columns all the time like Physics

Comment: Hi @domacs, Could you please elaborate your previous point of creating 4th table? I didn't get it.